# randomly choosing and filling datatype

Tags: haskell

So I have two data types. For simplicity say one holds an `Int` and one holds a `String`.

So let's say I have

```
data ranData = randInt Int | randString String
```

How can I make a function that will either choose one of these and then give it a random value. I have some ideas, but they are rather inelegant.

Comment: Remember type names and constructors must start with capital letters: `data RanData = RandInt Int | RandString String`.

Comment: This isn't two data types.  It's a single data type with two different constructors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to use the `MonadRandom` package:

```
import Data.Functor ((<$>))
import Control.Monad.Random

data RanData = RandInt Int | RandString String deriving Show

randomData :: (RandomGen g) => Rand g RanData
randomData = do
  shouldBeString <- getRandom -- Generate Bool
  if shouldBeString
    then do
      len <- getRandomR (0, 10) -- Generate Int between 0 and 10
      RandString . take len <$> getRandoms -- Take between 0 and 10 random chars
    else RandInt <$> getRandom -- Generate random Int

-- How to use:
main :: IO ()
main = print =<< evalRandIO randomData -- There are many other ways, too
```

The `randomData` function will generate a `RanData` in the `Rand` monad, with some random number generator `g`. The `evalRandIO` function will extract the random `RanData` using the `StdGen` random number generator. There are many other random number generators and ways to run them; this was only an example.

Answer (score 2):

QuickCheck has the [`Arbitrary` class](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/QuickCheck/latest/doc/html/Test-QuickCheck-Arbitrary.html#t%3aArbitrary) with some [useful functions](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/QuickCheck/latest/doc/html/Test-QuickCheck-Gen.html).

Your arbitrary instance would look identical to the pre-defined Either instance:

```
instance (Arbitrary a, Arbitrary b) => Arbitrary RanData where
  arbitrary = oneof [liftM RandInt arbitrary, liftM RandString arbitrary]

  shrink (RandInt x)  = [ RandInt  x' | x' <- shrink x ]
  shrink (RandString y) = [ RandString y' | y' <- shrink y ]
```

Comment: `QuickCheck` is very nice to work with, but it's a huge library to depend on if you only need randomness.

Comment: True, then again it's part of the haskell platform, and an `import Test.QuickCheck.Arbitrary` is really quite lightweight. It might save a lot of time

Comment: Yeah, but the library would still be linked into the executable, which would take up a lot of space; that's what I meant.